# How should I put parameter constraint to remove this error?

Tags: warning-messages

```
FindFit[data, {a/(1 + i*b*x^2), Element[{a, b}, Reals]}, {a, b}, x]
```

> FindFit::nrgnum: The gradient is not a vector of real numbers at {a,b}
>   = {1.,1.}. FindFit::grad: Evaluation of the gradient of function Experimental`NumericalFunction[{Hold[<<1>>],Block},{0,{{{},1,0,Hold[a],0,0},{{},1,1,Hold[b],0,0}}},{{{1,2,817},{{{Hold[Block[{<<4>>},CompoundExpression[<<3>>]]],Block},Automatic,None,1,Automatic},{}}}},{8,3,{},0},{904,MachinePrecision,{None,{Hold[Block[{x={<<1000>>},Optimization`FindFit`y$45202={<<1000>>}},1/2
> > Subtract[<<2>>].Subtract[<<2>>]]],Block}},True,{{Automatic,CleanUpRegisters->False,WarningMessages->False,EvaluateSymbolically->False,RuntimeErrorHandler->($Failed&)},{},Automatic,WVM},FindFit,Automatic,None},{None,None,None}]
>   failed at {1.,1.}.

Comment: The issue seems to be the `i`. Do you mean the complex unit `I`?

Comment: yes , I am trying to fit this complex function with real parameters .

Answer (score 3):

To my suprise there seems to be no method for nonlinear model fits to maps into $\mathbb{R}^n$ or to $\mathbb{C}$. Here is a simple implementation of the Gauss-Newton method that works at least in the given example:

```
MyNonlinearModelFit[pts0_, vals_, model_, pars_, vars_, pguess_] := 
 Module[{p, modelfun, cmodel, cDmodel, error, Derror, gradfit, 
   residual, iter, pts},
  pts = If[VectorQ[pts0],
    Transpose[{pts0}],
    pts0
    ];

  Quiet[Block[{p, pp, x, xx},
    pp = Table[p[[i]], {i, 1, Length[pars]}];
    xx = Table[x[[i]], {i, 1, Length[vars]}];
    modelfun = {x, p} \[Function] 
      Evaluate[model /. Thread[pars -> pp] /. Thread[vars -> xx]];
    With[{code = N[modelfun[xx, pp]] /. Part -> Compile`GetElement},
     cmodel = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {p, _Real, 1}},
       code,
       CompilationTarget -> "C",
       Parallelization -> True,
       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
       ]
     ];

    With[{code = 
       N[D[modelfun[xx, pp], {pp, 1}]] /. 
        Part -> Compile`GetElement},
     cDmodel = Compile[{{x, _Real, 1}, {p, _Real, 1}},
       code,
       CompilationTarget -> "C",
       Parallelization -> True,
       RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
       ]
     ];
    ]];

  p = pguess;
  error = Flatten[cmodel[pts, p] - vals];
  Derror = Flatten[cDmodel[pts, p], 1];
  iter = 0;
  gradfit = error.Derror;
  residual = Max[Abs[gradfit]]/Length[error];
  While[residual > 1. 10^-12,
   ++iter;
   p = p - 
     LinearSolve[Derror\[Transpose].Derror, gradfit, 
      Method -> "Cholesky"];
   error = Flatten[cmodel[pts, p] - vals];
   Derror = Flatten[cDmodel[pts, p], 1];
   gradfit = error.Derror;
   residual = Max[Abs[gradfit]]/Length[error]
   ];
  Thread[pars -> p]
  ]
```

Here is an example for the model given by the OP:

```
n = 100;
ptrue = {3., 2.};
SeedRandom[1234];
model = ComplexExpand[ReIm[a/(1 + I b x^2)]];
ftrue = x \[Function] Evaluate[model /. Thread[{a, b} -> ptrue]];
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n}];
vals = ftrue /@ pts + RandomVariate[
    MultinormalDistribution[{0, 0}, DiagonalMatrix[{1, 1}]], {n}];
pars = {a, b};
vars = {x};
pguess = {1., 0.};
fit = MyNonlinearModelFit[pts, vals, model, pars, vars, pguess]; //AbsoluteTiming
fit
ffitted = x \[Function] Evaluate[model /. fit];
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[
  Evaluate[{Join[{x}, ftrue[x]], Join[{x}, ffitted[x]]}],
  {x, Min[pts], Max[pts]}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"fitted curve", "true curve"}],
 Graphics3D[Point[Join[Transpose[{pts}], vals, 2]]],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

> {0.150965, Null}
>
> {a -> 3.04508, b -> 1.93957}

[image]

Since there are only two parameters involved, this works fine even for quite high amounts of data. (I tested it for up to 10 million data points.)